# What is the difference between console.log(), return etc

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between each of the following? I get the idea that they all put stuff to a web page. Are there any other similar methods which I should be aware of?

```
console.log("Hello world");
return("Hello world");
document.write("Hello world");
document.writeIn("Hello world");
document.innerHtml("Hello world");
```

Comment: console.log doesn't put anything into a web page.  It writes to the browser console (or wherever you have your console redirect to).  Nor does return ("hello world") by itself; document.write, writeln, and InnerHtml all have documented use cases. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main purpose of the **return** value, is to use the function return value like you would have use a variable value.
the **console.log()** is a function (you can see the brackets) that will write the argument value on the console. And only the debuging console, in a browser you will not see anything on the screen.

document.writeIn isn't a function, the proper function is called **document.writeln**. It's a lowercase "L" not a capital "i" pronounced "write line".
document.writeln(something)
is the same thing as:
document.write(something+"\n") //Might have been \r\n, I forget, either way it's a linebreak

**innerHTML** can be used to change the contents of the DOM by string munging. So if you wanted to add a paragraph with some text at the end of a selected element you could so.

Comment: Ah I see. Great thank you. I don't see why this question had a negative response to it.

Comment: because they all want you find it on your own...you can easily google out the differences @dunn_rite